# Why use Angular Modules?

Tags: angularjs

I have an angular application that looks like such.

file1.js

```
var app = angular.module('app', ['third-party-stuff-A']
```

file2.js

```
var app = angular.module('app', ['third-party-stuff-B']
```

so essentially file1 and file2 represent two separate pages in my application.

I've registered all my controllers, services, and other injectables into the module app, so for example.

```
app.factory('thing', function ($scope) { ... });
```

the `thing` factory is available to both app in file1 and app in file2.

I've read that it's better practice to break things into modules. app in file1 and file2 should probably be their own separate module.
And to go even a step further, perhaps `thing` factory can go into a module `MyFactories`. and `MyFactories` would be injected into each of my apps.

But I'm not sure what the immediate benefit is of doing this.

Comment: `plug-n-play` portability is one benefit. Organization by feature is another.

Comment: I read in some articles that it could be possible that Angular will provide lazy loading in the future, in which seperation in modules take place.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Most `applications` have one `main` method and links to different parts of the application.
Angular apps don't have a main method. Instead modules specify how an application should be bootstrapped. advantages for creating modules are

1. You can package code as reusable modules. The modules can be loaded
2. in any order (or even in parallel) because modules delay execution.
   see more at https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/module

Comment: angular module does not provide module loading, module dependency, and namespace. why not use requirejs module instead?